# How to install sql 2008 R2 reporting service AFTER SP2010 is installed?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, installation

We are setting up a SP2010 environment. The SharePoint farm is ready and it is connecting to a SQL2008 R2 instance.

Then I realize I also need the SQL reporting service. So that I can show reports (rdl files) on SharePoint. When I come across this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677368(v=sql.105).aspx#bkmk_TOInstallReportingServicesandtheDatabaseEngine), it suggested the install order:

1. Install both Reporting Services and the Database Engine
2. Run the SharePoint 2010 Products Preparation tool.
3. Install SharePoint Server 2010

However I have already complete the install and setup for SharePoint 2010 + Project server 2010.... I don't want to remove everything and do it all over... Could you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install reporting service feature **after** SharePoint and project server are installed , you just need to add a new feature (reporting service feature) to the current existing instance  by doing the following:

- Just mount the same SQL server media that you are used to installing SQL server at first time or the same version to the database server .
- Run the setup file > Click Installation on the left side of the Wizard and then click New installation or add features to an existing installation.
- Follow the wizard till coming at this step of installation type.
- Don't create a new instance , just check add features to an existing instance and select the currently installed instance.
- At Feature selection select only reporting service because the database engine is already select at the first SQL installation.
- Continue the wizard and select the mode that you need (Native Mode - Integrated Mode)

Now the Reporting services Feature should be installed .

**Note :**

In Native Mode , you can access the reports from Report Manager URL / or Report services URL. and in this case, this URL may be accessible only from DB server , and not accessible outside it based on the current zone.

So to overcome this issue  ,

- you should install a new instance at SharePoint Server with only reporting service feature ,
- then at Reporting Service Configuration Manager , you can configure the Report Server DB to the Main SQL Server Instance ,

Now the Report Manager URL will be accessible and browsable outside the DB server. and the Report Database is hosted at the Main DB Server.